# Dimension attribute with one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I have a request for an attribute in a dimension that has a one-to-many relationship with the lower level of the dimension.

Here is the case:

- Dimension: Employee
- Attribute: Immatriculation

I have 3 source tables : Employee, Language and LanguageLevel.

One employee can have multiple immatriculation codes. Each immatriculation has a number, start_date, expiration_date.

How can I model this case ?

Comment: What sorts of questions are you hoping to answer involving these attributes?  Dimensional Modeling decisions can't be made without knowing that.

Comment: I am preparing a fact called DNA which will regroup information about an employee. I decided to not have the language as a dimension because it is not a business entity. And as we know we cannot have duplicate records in a dimension which is my case if I add language as an attribute in my employee dimension , because an employee can have many languages.